# How to access XamlRoot from a non-UI thread?

Tags: c#, winui-3, winui, windows-app-sdk

I am making a WASDK WinUI 3 app.
In my App.xaml.cs, I have this:

```
public static XamlRoot AppXamlRoot { get; set; }
```

Then, on my main window, I've got this:

```
private void MainGrid_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    App.AppXamlRoot = this.Content.XamlRoot;
}
```

MainGrid is a Grid element in the XAML code.
Finally, on a ViewModel class, I have an async method that uses the App.AppXamlRoot, which should be accessible because it is static and App class declaration is accessible from the whole C# project. In my async method, the App.AppXamlRoot throws a COM exception.

```
await MyMessageBox.Show($"{ex.Message}\n\n{ex.InnerException}", App.AppXamlRoot);
```

Comment: How did you access UI elements? with [DispatcherQueue](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/windows-app-sdk/migrate-to-windows-app-sdk/guides/threading#change-windowsuicorecoredispatcher-to-microsoftuidispatchingdispatcherqueue)? For example, [CustomControls](https://github.com/microsoft/WindowsAppSDK-Samples/blob/7b3029a2c3fb21b37d3204880f18fd9f15142f8c/Samples/CustomControls/CppApp/MainPage.xaml.cpp#L40).

Comment: You cannot access UI elements from a non-UI thread. You will have to marshal any code that access UI elements to the UI thread using the `DispatcherQueue`.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to access the UI from a non-UI thread, you need to use the `DispatcherQueue`.

For example, in your App.xaml.cs:

```cs
public static DispatcherQueue DispatcherQueue { get; } = DispatcherQueue.GetForCurrentThread();
```

and use it like this:

```cs
App.DispatcherQueue.TryEnqueue(async () =>
{
    // Acceess the UI here...
}
```